# Is there a production stable RDBMS module for RingoJS

Tags: hibernate, rhino, serverside-javascript, ringojs

I just ported a web app from Java/Tomcat to RingoJS and threw out tons of ceremony code and configuration. This Javascript AppServer is just great. So far I used the integrated JSON file storage, but now have to add database support (H2). There is a ringo-sqlstore and a ringo-hibernate module. Does anybody have experience with stability, performance, ease of development - recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I guess none of the two are really mature, which means you'll probably detect some rough edges as you go.

Of course Hibernate itself is a very mature project, but it's also quite large and complex. I'd say there are less chances stumble over bugs with ringo-hibernate, but on the other hand problems with ringo-sqlstore may be easier to understand and fix.